# MYSQL - Multiple table update issue

Tags: php, mysql, updates

Ive read multiple answers but none seem to work for me.

I have two tables Cus_acc_details & Cus_Register:

Cus_acc_detail

```
1 : CustomerID
2 : Acctid
3  : CUS_Fname
4  : Cus_Lname
5  : CUS_Phone
6  : Cus_Email
```

Us_Register

```
1  : Cus_Email
2  : Cus_Password
3  : Cus_confirm_Password
```

I want to update all fields from Cus_acc_detail and only Cus_Email for Cus_register.
I have the following :

```
   <?php
   $user = $_SESSION["Cus_Email"];
   if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {


  $UpdateFname = $_POST['fname'];
  $UpdateLname = $_POST['Lname'];
  $UpdateEmail = $_POST['email'];
  $UpdatePhone = $_POST['phone'];
  }

  $sql = $dbc->query("UPDATE Cus_Register r INNER JOIN Cus_acc_details d ON( r.Cus_Email = d.Cus_Email) SET CUS_Fname = ' $UpdateFname', CUS_Lname = ' $UpdateLname', CUS_Email = ' $UpdateEmail', Cus_Phone = ' $UpdatePhone' WHERE CUS_Email = '$user' ");
 header('Location: Cus_Account.php');
 ?>
```

The page simply just does not update, could someone possibly point out where i have gone wrong.

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply ASSUMING that your query call succeeded,  or was even called in the first place. you need to start debugging. `var_dump($_POST)` and see what arrived at the server. start checking return values or catching exeptions from the db calls, etc...

Comment: and given that query, I'm guessing it failed outright, because you failed to quote `$user` for the `CUS_Email` field. `WHERE CUS_Email = president@whitehouse.gov` is going to barf - that email address is not a field in your table, and since there's no quotes on it, it's not a string to be used for comparison

Comment: first of all you have an error `Cus_Register.Cus_Email =Cus_Register.Cus_Email`. Should be `Cus_acc_detail.Cus_Email =Cus_Register.Cus_Email`..... second - when you write `CUS_Email` mysql doesn't know which table to update, because this field exists in two tables

Comment: @АлексейШиманский so is it better to do  two different queries as i want both Cus_Email to update

Comment: @MarcB sorry i have actually updated my code a while ago, this is old code. I will update.

Comment: @jerneva I think you should to do database normalization. E-mail should be in one of the tables. Other table should be related with first by id..... cause query `update Cus_Register set Cus_Register.CUS_Email = somethin  where Cus_Register.CUS_Email = someVal` looks weird

Comment: try `$sql = $dbc->query("UPDATE Cus_Register, Cus_acc_details
SET Cus_acc_details.CUS_Fname = ' $UpdateFname', Cus_acc_details.CUS_Lname = ' $UpdateLname', Cus_acc_details.CUS_Email = ' $UpdateEmail', Cus_acc_details.Cus_Phone = ' $UpdatePhone', Cus_Register.CUS_Email = ' $UpdateEmail', 
WHERE Cus_Register.Cus_Email = Cus_acc_details.Cus_Email AND Cus_Register.Cus_Email = '$user' ");`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Thank you so much. it is updating, but creating new columns each time. I am current working out how to make my AUTO_INCREMENT into a variable to use the customer instead of email

Answer (score 0):

Field `CUS_Email` should be specified for both tables in `SET`.

```
UPDATE Cus_Register r INNER JOIN Cus_acc_details d ON( r.Cus_Email = d.Cus_Email) SET CUS_Fname = ' $UpdateFname', CUS_Lname = ' $UpdateLname', r.CUS_Email = ' $UpdateEmail', d.CUS_Email = ' $UpdateEmail', Cus_Phone = ' $UpdatePhone' WHERE CUS_Email = '$user'
```